# Vite/Vuejs primeicons not being properly displayed on deployed server

Tags: nginx, vuejs3, vite, primevue

After updates to vite/vue project, primeicons is no longer working correctly on remote server but works fine on local dev machine and local staging server.

I updated vue, primevue, primeicons and primeflex together with vite together with adding some new functionality.

Prior to update the remote server was performing as expected. After the update everything works perfectly on my development system (macos) as well as my local staging server (Ubuntu 22) but shows gibberish for icons via remote backend server (a Ubuntu 20.x server which wasn't update as part of the this process).

Deployment consists of building `dist` folder using vite's build command and then copying this dist folder to relevant servers where the dist folder is served via NGINX (which has not been changed/updated on my remote server)

My development machine (macos) simply serves http and not https, my local staging server has nginx configured to serve https with local certificates. The remote server and staging server have nearly identical nginx configuration.

So far investigation has revealed little reason - my findings so far are:

### SSH into Local linux.

Using cat -A to view contents of primeicons-358f66d8.css shows same content as remote server.

- Local Staging server

```
.pi-home:before{content:"M-nM-$M-%"}.pi-spinner:before{content:"M-nM-$M-&"}$
```

- Remote server

```
.pi-home:before{content:"M-nM-$M-%"}.pi-spinner:before{content:"M-nM-$M-&"}$
```

Connecting with chrome browser and using its webinspector and looking at Sources  `assets/primeicons-358f66d8.css` shows different entries between local systems and the remote linux box

- Local Staging server

```
.pi-spinner:before {
    content: ""
}
```

- Remote server

```
.pi-spinner:before {
    content: "î¤¦"
}
```

This `î¤¦` is what I see in place of icon but only on remote server.

Webinspector's Network shows no failures to load any files and no errors are reported to console.

Vite's build process also doesn't throw any warnings or errors.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I noticed that on my remote server I wasn't setting charset to utf-8 in nginx config. Making this change solved the issue.

I am not sure why it had worked for years prior to the update and I also thought that utf-8 was the default charset.